# What is the best way to create a sparse array in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, hash, maps

I am working on a project that requires the manipulation of enormous matrices, specifically pyramidal summation for a copula calculation.

In short, I need to keep track of a relatively small number of values (usually a value of 1, and in rare cases more than 1) in a sea of zeros in the matrix (multidimensional array).

A sparse array allows the user to store a small number of values, and assume all undefined records to be a preset value. Since it is not physically possible to store all values in memory, I need to store only a few non-zero elements. This could be several million entries.

Speed is a huge priority, and I would also like to dynamically choose the number of variables in the class at runtime.

I currently work on a system that uses a binary search tree (b-tree) to store entries. Does anyone know of a better system?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For C++, a map works well.  Several million objects won't be a problem.  10 million items took about 4.4 seconds and about 57 meg on my computer.

My test application is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>

class triple {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    bool operator<(const triple &other) const {
        if (x < other.x) return true;
        if (other.x < x) return false;
        if (y < other.y) return true;
        if (other.y < y) return false;
        return z < other.z;
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::map<triple,int> data;
    triple point;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        point.x = rand();
        point.y = rand();
        point.z = rand();
        //printf("%d %d %d %d\n", i, point.x, point.y, point.z);
        data[point] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now to dynamically choose the number of variables, the easiest solution is to represent **index as a string**, and then use string as a key for the map. For instance, an item located at [23][55] can be represented via "23,55" string. We can also extend this solution for higher dimensions; such as for three dimensions an arbitrary index  will look like "34,45,56". A simple implementation of this technique is as follows:

```
std::map data<string,int> data;
char ix[100];

sprintf(ix, "%d,%d", x, y); // 2 vars
data[ix] = i;

sprintf(ix, "%d,%d,%d", x, y, z); // 3 vars
data[ix] = i;
```

Comment: what about performance of getting the element range from this or checking if the range is fully in the array?

Comment: The implementation of operator< is incorrect. Consider Triple{1,2,3} and Triple{3,2,1}, neither will be less than the other. A correct implementation would check x then y then z sequentially instead of all at once.

Comment: Since it hadn't been fixed for an extended time, I took the liberty to replace it with a correct implementation.

Comment: Seconds for only a million elements? That seems quite bad. You should consider using a hashing function and `unordered_map`. Check out https://github.com/victorprad/InfiniTAM They use the hash `((x * 73856093u) ^ (y * 19349669u) ^ (z * 83492791u))` and can integrate millions of samples into a sparse 3D grid at good framerates.

Answer (score 25):

The accepted answer recommends using strings to represent multi-dimensional indices.

However, constructing strings is needlessly wasteful for this. If the size isn’t known at compile time (and thus `std::tuple` doesn’t work), `std::vector` works well as an index, both with hash maps and ordered trees. For `std::map`, this is almost trivial:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using index_type = std::vector<int>;

template <typename T>
using sparse_array = std::map<index_type, T>;
```

For `std::unordered_map` (or similar hash table-based dictionaries) it’s slightly more work, since `std::vector` does not specialise `std::hash`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <numeric>

using index_type = std::vector<int>;

struct index_hash {
    std::size_t operator()(index_type const& i) const noexcept {
        // Like boost::hash_combine; there might be some caveats, see
        // <https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978188/1968>
        auto const hash_combine = [](auto seed, auto x) {
            return std::hash<int>()(x) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
        };
        return std::accumulate(i.begin() + 1, i.end(), i[0], hash_combine);
    }
};

template <typename T>
using sparse_array = std::unordered_map<index_type, T, index_hash>;
```

Either way, the usage is the same:

```
int main() {
    using i = index_type;

    auto x = sparse_array<int>();
    x[i{1, 2, 3}] = 42;
    x[i{4, 3, 2}] = 23;

    std::cout << x[i{1, 2, 3}] + x[i{4, 3, 2}] << '\n'; // 65
}
```

Comment: aka. unordered_map

Comment: @KonradRudolph, isn't non collision unordered_map time complexity, Big 0, 1? If yes, isn't it same with hash table?

Comment: @CloudCho Not sure what you mean, but `std::unordered_map` *is* a hash table.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought you had suggested Vector not Unoreded_map for hash table.

Answer (score 13):

Boost has a templated implementation of BLAS called uBLAS that contains a sparse matrix.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 7):

Complete list of solutions can be found in the wikipedia. For convenience, I have quoted relevant sections as follows.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Dictionary_of_keys_.28DOK.29

**Dictionary of keys (DOK)**

> DOK consists of a dictionary that maps (row, column)-pairs to the
>   value of the elements. Elements that are missing from the dictionary
>   are taken to be zero. The format is good for incrementally
>   constructing a sparse matrix in random order, but poor for iterating
>   over non-zero values in lexicographical order. One typically
>   constructs a matrix in this format and then converts to another more
>   efficient format for processing.[1]

**List of lists (LIL)**

> LIL stores one list per row, with each entry containing the column
>   index and the value. Typically, these entries are kept sorted by
>   column index for faster lookup. This is another format good for
>   incremental matrix construction.[2]

**Coordinate list (COO)**

> COO stores a list of (row, column, value) tuples. Ideally, the entries
>   are sorted (by row index, then column index) to improve random access
>   times. This is another format which is good for incremental matrix
>   construction.[3]

**Compressed sparse row (CSR, CRS or Yale format)**

> The compressed sparse row (CSR) or compressed row storage (CRS) format
>   represents a matrix M by three (one-dimensional) arrays, that
>   respectively contain nonzero values, the extents of rows, and column
>   indices. It is similar to COO, but compresses the row indices, hence
>   the name. This format allows fast row access and matrix-vector
>   multiplications (Mx).

Answer (score 5):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) is a C++ linear algebra library that has an [implementation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__SparseQuickRefPage.html) of a sparse matrix. It even supports matrix operations and solvers (LU factorization etc) that are optimized for sparse matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Small detail in the index comparison. You need to do a lexicographical compare, otherwise:

```
a= (1, 2, 1); b= (2, 1, 2);
(a<b) == (b<a) is true, but b!=a
```

Edit: So the comparison should probably be:

```
return lhs.x<rhs.x
    ? true 
    : lhs.x==rhs.x 
        ? lhs.y<rhs.y 
            ? true 
            : lhs.y==rhs.y
                ? lhs.z<rhs.z
                : false
        : false
```

Answer (score 3):

Hash tables have a fast insertion and look up. You could write a simple hash function since you know you'd be dealing with only integer pairs as the keys.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement sparse matrices is to not to implement them - atleast not on your own. I would suggest to BLAS (which I think is a part of LAPACK) which can handle really huge matrices.

Comment: LAPACK is a library for dense matrices. The standard BLAS is also for dense matrices. There is a Sparse BLAS package (through NIST) but this is different then the standard BLAS.

Answer (score 0):

Since only values with [a][b][c]...[w][x][y][z] are of consequence, we only store the indice themselves, not the value 1 which is just about everywhere - always the same + no way to hash it. Noting that the curse of dimensionality is present, suggest go with some established tool NIST or Boost, at least read the sources for that to circumvent needless blunder.

If the work needs to capture the temporal dependence distributions and parametric tendencies of unknown data sets, then a Map or B-Tree with uni-valued root is probably not practical. We can store only the indice themselves, hashed if ordering ( sensibility for presentation ) can subordinate to reduction of time domain at run-time, for all 1 values. Since non-zero values other than one are few, an obvious candidate for those is whatever data-structure you can find readily and understand. If the data set is truly vast-universe sized I suggest some sort of sliding window that manages file / disk / persistent-io yourself,  moving portions of the data into scope as need be. ( writing code that you can understand )  If you are under commitment to provide actual solution to a working group, failure to do so leaves you at the mercy of consumer grade operating systems that have the sole goal of taking your lunch away from you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple implementation that should provide a reasonable fast lookup (using a hash table) as well as fast iteration over non-zero elements in a row/column.

```
// Copyright 2014 Leo Osvald
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#ifndef UTIL_IMMUTABLE_SPARSE_MATRIX_HPP_
#define UTIL_IMMUTABLE_SPARSE_MATRIX_HPP_

#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// A simple time-efficient implementation of an immutable sparse matrix
// Provides efficient iteration of non-zero elements by rows/cols,
// e.g. to iterate over a range [row_from, row_to) x [col_from, col_to):
//   for (int row = row_from; row < row_to; ++row) {
//     for (auto col_range = sm.nonzero_col_range(row, col_from, col_to);
//          col_range.first != col_range.second; ++col_range.first) {
//       int col = *col_range.first;
//       // use sm(row, col)
//       ...
//     }
template<typename T = double, class Coord = int>
class SparseMatrix {
  struct PointHasher;
  typedef std::map< Coord, std::vector<Coord> > NonZeroList;
  typedef std::pair<Coord, Coord> Point;

 public:
  typedef T ValueType;
  typedef Coord CoordType;
  typedef typename NonZeroList::mapped_type::const_iterator CoordIter;
  typedef std::pair<CoordIter, CoordIter> CoordIterRange;

  SparseMatrix() = default;

  // Reads a matrix stored in MatrixMarket-like format, i.e.:
  // <num_rows> <num_cols> <num_entries>
  // <row_1> <col_1> <val_1>
  // ...
  // Note: the header (lines starting with '%' are ignored).
  template<class InputStream, size_t max_line_length = 1024>
  void Init(InputStream& is) {
    rows_.clear(), cols_.clear();
    values_.clear();

    // skip the header (lines beginning with '%', if any)
    decltype(is.tellg()) offset = 0;
    for (char buf[max_line_length + 1];
         is.getline(buf, sizeof(buf)) && buf[0] == '%'; )
      offset = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(offset);

    size_t n;
    is >> row_count_ >> col_count_ >> n;
    values_.reserve(n);
    while (n--) {
      Coord row, col;
      typename std::remove_cv<T>::type val;
      is >> row >> col >> val;
      values_[Point(--row, --col)] = val;
      rows_[col].push_back(row);
      cols_[row].push_back(col);
    }
    SortAndShrink(rows_);
    SortAndShrink(cols_);
  }

  const T& operator()(const Coord& row, const Coord& col) const {
    static const T kZero = T();
    auto it = values_.find(Point(row, col));
    if (it != values_.end())
      return it->second;
    return kZero;
  }

  CoordIterRange
  nonzero_col_range(Coord row, Coord col_from, Coord col_to) const {
    CoordIterRange r;
    GetRange(cols_, row, col_from, col_to, &r);
    return r;
  }

  CoordIterRange
  nonzero_row_range(Coord col, Coord row_from, Coord row_to) const {
    CoordIterRange r;
    GetRange(rows_, col, row_from, row_to, &r);
    return r;
  }

  Coord row_count() const { return row_count_; }
  Coord col_count() const { return col_count_; }
  size_t nonzero_count() const { return values_.size(); }
  size_t element_count() const { return size_t(row_count_) * col_count_; }

 private:
  typedef std::unordered_map<Point,
                             typename std::remove_cv<T>::type,
                             PointHasher> ValueMap;

  struct PointHasher {
    size_t operator()(const Point& p) const {
      return p.first << (std::numeric_limits<Coord>::digits >> 1) ^ p.second;
    }
  };

  static void SortAndShrink(NonZeroList& list) {
    for (auto& it : list) {
      auto& indices = it.second;
      indices.shrink_to_fit();
      std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end());
    }

    // insert a sentinel vector to handle the case of all zeroes
    if (list.empty())
      list.emplace(Coord(), std::vector<Coord>(Coord()));
  }

  static void GetRange(const NonZeroList& list, Coord i, Coord from, Coord to,
                       CoordIterRange* r) {
    auto lr = list.equal_range(i);
    if (lr.first == lr.second) {
      r->first = r->second = list.begin()->second.end();
      return;
    }

    auto begin = lr.first->second.begin(), end = lr.first->second.end();
    r->first = lower_bound(begin, end, from);
    r->second = lower_bound(r->first, end, to);
  }

  ValueMap values_;
  NonZeroList rows_, cols_;
  Coord row_count_, col_count_;
};

#endif  /* UTIL_IMMUTABLE_SPARSE_MATRIX_HPP_ */
```

For simplicity, it's `immutable`, but you can can make it mutable; be sure to change `std::vector` to `std::set` if you want a reasonable efficient "insertions" (changing a zero to a non-zero).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> coord_t;
typedef boost::hash<coord_t> coord_hash_t;
typedef std::unordered_map<coord_hash_t, int, c_hash_t> sparse_array_t;

sparse_array_t the_data;
the_data[ { x, y, z } ] = 1; /* list-initialization is cool */

for( const auto& element : the_data ) {
    int xx, yy, zz, val;
    std::tie( std::tie( xx, yy, zz ), val ) = element;
    /* ... */
}
```

To help keep your data sparse, you might want to write a subclass of `unorderd_map`, whose iterators automatically skip over (and erase) any items with a value of 0.