# Compiler hang when initializing large std::arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I need to initialize a very large multidimensional `std::array` of data:

```
class Thing;

class World
{
public:
    World() : space{nullptr} {};
    ~World() = default;
private:
    static unsigned int const size = 1000;
    std::array<std::array<std::array<std::unique_ptr<Thing>, size>, size>, size> space;
};
```

If you try to instantiate this, G++ 4.8.2 chokes:  it consumes all the available memory and will not return.  That is, the compiler hangs and I never get an executable.  **Why is this?**  Note that clang++ has no trouble.

Note:  I fully realize that putting this much data on the stack can overflow it.  **What is the best way to initialize it on the heap?**  I think making `space` a reference (to allocated memory) would be the best way, but I can't figure the syntax out.

Comment: Does the *compiler* choke? Or does the compiled program choke at runtime?

Comment: If this is instantiated as simply `World world;` you're consuming slightly more than `1000^3 * sizeof(std::unique_ptr<>)` bytes. on a 64 bit system that would be a *minimum* 7.629 **GB**. So yeah, I'd say you crossed a line on the automatic variable space limit. I am *dying* to know the problem this is intended to solve.

Comment: The compiler, g++ 4.8.2, will not return.

Comment: @WhozCraig, this is a contrived example; I'm not instantiating anything this massive, but it illustrates my point.

Comment: Ah. ok. so your *compiler* chokes (code fails to compile??), not the actual program ? What is the resultant error message? **Is `World` global or have static linkage?** ? if so you may have just hit the link-limit.

Comment: Yes.  There's not an error, I simply cannot get an executable before the machine runs out of RAM.  No idea why this would consume so much memory at compile time.  Reducing the size of the `array` to, say, 200x200x3 allows it to finish with a peak RAM usage of about 2GB.  `World world` has static linkage (it's instantiated in `main`).

Comment: I just tried compiling this (Changing Thing to int) and it compiled. Can you give a small example that demonstrates the compiler failing?

Comment: @FDinoff Now put `World world;` as a *global* and compile again. I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: yeah mine did too, but I'm using clang, not g++. I need to go hit this on ideone and see if I can make it puke. Edit: after creating a global *and* ensuring it is referenced functionally so as not to optimize out (I was release-building) I managed to eat 4GB of ram on the loader, but at least it loaded. Still haven't tried g++.

Comment: @WhozCraig same I was using clang++. I just switched to g++ and its still running...

Comment: @FDinoff be ready with Ctrl-C! Can confirm that clang++ has no trouble. No difference with global vs static.

Comment: @WhozCraig not running locally hopefully no body at my school is using the machine for anything. Just got this 
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions. Used all 24GB of ram on the computer

Comment: @FDinoff *awesome*. There are times I like gnu; this isn't one of them. Does that happen even without the global or static linkage var? I'm now seriously interested in this. (I'm on a Mac with 5.02 Xcode tools, so no g++ joy here, turns-out-thankfully). I want to say g++ is generating the loadable object code and is stretched to its limit, whereas clang is doing *something* smarter.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty I can't explain why this pukes on g++ other than my suspicions about it building the object module with all those DDs embedded. I did post an alternative that *might* work for you in the interim. Hope it helps.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah it looks likes its failing while trying to just compile the class. I used the flags `g++ -std=c++11 -c` (I think this makes it only compile) and I removed the globals.

Comment: @FDinoff Thats exactly what that should do, I see nothing wrong with that at all (you did it right). That you went the extra mile to compile just the module to object code (`-c`) so no link-step and it *still* pukes is somewhat telling.

Comment: @WhozCraig the worst part is if it did eventually compile the object file would only be 1.3K. I tried it with size at 50, 100 and 200. (I think I saw top max at 50% men usage (of 24GB) for the `size = 200`)

Comment: @FDinoff Yeah, I think if he vector's the outer-most part of this it may work for him in the interim, but I feel a little iffy on that only because it somewhat kicks the can down the road. The same problem would likely resurface with large enough numbers.

Comment: This looks like [GCC Bug #59659](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59659): the compiler generates *enormous* initializer code for large `std::array` by initializing each element directly.

Comment: @Casey: This is what I suspected, I remember killing Clang when trying to introduce a massive C-array of user-defined classes. With `int` there is no initialization so everything is fine but `unique_ptr` has a user-defined constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i can't explain the nuance of why g++ is puking on this, but until you work that out, consider this for your member declaration:

```
std::vector<std::array<std::array<std::unique_ptr<Thing>,size>,size>> space;
```

and in the constructor initializer list:

```
World() : space{size}
```

That should at least get you compiling and move all this to the heap. Note: this better be a 64bit process. I'm going to have to hunt to find out why g++ is doing what I suspect it is doing.

Comment: This compiled with `size = 4000000000` in less than a second.

Comment: I feel like there is a way to do this with space as a `unique_ptr` to the 3D `array` construct and initializing it with the proper call to `new` (and modifying all the usage appropriately to dereference) but I can't work that constructor syntax out either just yet.  Regardless, this works.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty so long as you have something to work with. You certainly could do this with a std::unique_ptr<> at the outer reaches and allocate yourself, but if you need that at runtime, you can do the same just by reserving and emplacing as needed through World members and hit up the vector. At least this gets you on the heap and out of automatic storage. I'll try and do some bugs hunting and see if there is something on this already reported  when I get the spare cycles. Glad you have something interim to work with. Wish you could prop FDinoff for this as well. He put some work in it.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty or WhozCraig do either of you have an account at the gnu bug tracker and would be willing to submit the bug report there? Or should I just do it?

Comment: I may have an account but if you would rather handle it that would be fine with me.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty I actually don't, so one of you will have to do it. sry for that inconvenience. But hey, *you* found it =P

Comment: Alright. I'll do it when "I get some spare cycles" (I like that and I'm taking it ;). Thank you both for the help.  And if you figure out the reason why and are bored one day, I would love to hear the reason.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `unique_ptr` it looks like you are looking for a sparse 3d-matrix like type. For implementing a sparse matrix you could have a look at [What is the best way to create a sparse array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-sparse-array-in-c) and as an implementation detail you could use [Boost Multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) for implementing fast access to all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<vector<unique_ptr<Thing>>>> space;
```

and when initializing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   vector<vector<unique_ptr<Thing>>> sp1;
   for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
   {
      vector<unique_ptr<Thing>> sp2;
      for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
         sp2.push_back(make_unique<Thing>("params", "to", "construct", "thing"));

       sp1.push_back(move(sp2));
   }

   space.push_back(move(sp1));
}
```

It is similar to your approach, but it constructs the vectors in the heap instead of stack.