# Statically allocated, optimizable, sparse key-value store in C?

Tags: arrays, c, enums, key-value-store

Let's say, I want to use 16-bit unsigned integers to describe some category (say, as in the example below, fruits); and:

- I want to specify a total of all these categories first, - and then choose a subset at compile time which is actually used in my program; with only the actual amount of memory used being allocated

... and, more specifically:

- The integers/categories are not in order, i.e. there are are "holes", which raises the issue of "sparse arrays" (see related [What is the best way to create a sparse array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-sparse-array-in-c))
- I would like to use the integers/categories as indices into an array of strings associated to the categories - so, essentially, this represents a key/value store (that is, a "dict")

Functionally, the below example more or less achieves that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

enum fruit         
{
  FRUIT_APPLE  = 0x1000, 
  FRUIT_ORANGE = 0x1001, 
  FRUIT_PEAR   = 0x2001,
  FRUIT_QUINCE = 0x2002,
  FRUIT_GRAPE  = 0x3000,
  /* etc. */
  FRUIT_MAX
};

// choosing which fruits to use here:
#define USE_APPLE
#define USE_ORANGE
#define USE_QUINCE

const char * const fruit_str[] =
{
  #ifdef USE_APPLE
  [FRUIT_APPLE]  = "my apple",
  #endif //USE_APPLE
  #ifdef USE_ORANGE
  [FRUIT_ORANGE] = "my orange",
  #endif //USE_ORANGE
  #ifdef USE_PEAR
  [FRUIT_PEAR]   = "special pear",
  #endif //USE_PEAR
  #ifdef USE_QUINCE
  [FRUIT_QUINCE] = "special quince",
  #endif //USE_QUINCE
  #ifdef USE_GRAPE
  [FRUIT_GRAPE]  = "epic grape",
  #endif //USE_GRAPE
  /* etc. */
};


int main() {
  printf("Size of fruit_str: %zu\n", sizeof(fruit_str));
  #ifdef USE_APPLE
  printf("Got apple: '%s'\n", fruit_str[FRUIT_APPLE]);
  #endif //USE_APPLE
  return 0;
}
```

A bit too many ifdefs to be cleanly readable, I guess (although one could probably use some preprocessor trickery as in, say, [How to convert enum names to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c) to make it a bit more readable) - but, ultimately: my "sum total" definition of categories is in `enum fruit`; I choose what I want used in my program via definition of `USE_(fruit)` macros; and I for those "used", I can recall the associated string directly through the category integer, say `fruit_str[FRUIT_APPLE]`.

(this kind of setup will also raise a compiler warning for two same numeric values in `enum fruit` (not because of restrictions on `enum`, but because those values are used to initialize slots in an array of strings), which I also appreciate - as the category integers are supposed to be unique)

Except, if I compile and run this program (say in https://replit.com/languages/c), I get:

```
> ./main
Size of fruit_str: 65560
Got apple: 'my apple'
```

Well, size of `fruit_str` of 65560 is a ... bit much, given what I actually want to store as data (and here it is "my apple", "my orange", and "special quince", which is some 32 bytes, or 35 including null terminators).

So, is there a better way to achieve this kind of a statically allocated key/value (where the keys as "sparse") store in C, so it is "optimizable" - that is, so the memory allocated correctly scales with the amount of keys chosen to be compiled in the store?

Comment: Well you could implement a hash map (dict). May be a bit much perhaps but it's a good learning exercise, I have done it before :)