# Resize tightly packed array without copying data

Tags: c++, arrays, size, heap-memory, shrink

I was wondering whether it's possible to resize a dynamically allocated array without copying the data. More specifically, when I allocate an array on the heap with a size of 10, and I write some values in the first 5 places, those values should lay right next to each other in memory right? So if I wanted to resize the array so that it only contains those 5 first values, is there a way to "shrink' the size of the array without needing to copy everything to another array with the right size?

Like can I just shrink the array to the lower size and free the rest of the memory?

Comment: What you want with manual memory management is not how c++ works. You probably should just use std::vector and forget about manual memory management.

Comment: In order to change the capacity of an array, the array needs to be reallocated.  You could overload placement `new` to do inplace "shrinking" of an array.

Comment: Probably not possible. And anyway, the management for splitting and returning half an allocation would use much more resources than copying 5 ints.

Comment: Just move the required content to a smaller std::vector<T> (and make sure that T has a noexcept move constructor, and yes that will still copy memory but as efficient as it can do). Or just accept the fact you have a bit of memory that is not used. If you have a device with little memory you are probably not using dynamically allocated memory anyway.

Comment: In my decades of embedded systems programming (on memory constrained platforms), I've never had to shrink an array during runtime.  There are other more important issues to consider than memory shrinking.

Comment: As far as you can tell from C++, an array will be contiguous storage. What's actually going on in the hardware on the other side of a virtual memory manager can be... much more interesting. For example, you probably won't see this in a 10 element array, if you request enough storage to fill up 2 pages and then only fill half, that second page might not represent any hardware yet. There's no point to doing the work to get actual memory if no one's used it yet. Shrinking might not be necessary at all. Even if you do shrink, there are no guarantees that the portion you don't need is given back

Comment: Just to clarify: I am working with (millions of) voxels, and I only wanna know where the active voxels are. So there might be hundreds of thousands active voxels, and allocating an array that could potentionally save every voxel and thwn resizing it to only hold the active ones would use quite some time, won't it?

Comment: It could. System may have to allocate a new, smaller block of memory and then your code does a bunch of copying. Usually not worth the time spent unless you really need that storage somewhere else. But consider that a smart memory manager (and by modern standards, not that smart a manager) will take note of this unused or rarely used pages of memory and swap them out to a slower form of storage so that other users can use the memory. And you did absolutely nothing--your code didn't get any more complicated--to make it happen.

Comment: Maybe you need some type of sparse array: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-sparse-array-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-sparse-array-in-c)

Comment: That's what `std::string::resize` does: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize and there's the `std::string::shrink_to_fit` that decrease capacity down to size: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit

Comment: Note the bit in the linked documentation that says that `shrink_to_fit` is specified as non-binding. It can be implemented to do absolutely no shrinking of any kind.